# Trying to set up Regular expression validation after submitted form with TextInput in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

Hello i'm trying to use regex after submitted a form.
So i use OnEndEditing and call a function with regex :

```
 const checkEnteredValues = (inputValue) => {
    inputValue.replace(/[A-Z]/g, '')
  }
```

Then i call the function withe the text updated from the input with setTask

```
<TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              keyboardType="visible-password"
              placeholderTextColor='white'
              placeholder="What needs to be done ?"
              value={task}
              maxFontSizeMultiplier={1}
              autoFocus
              onChangeText={setTask}
              onEndEditing={checkEnteredValues(task)}
              onSubmitEditing={handleSubmit}>
```

But it does not work. I'm missing something ?
I've tried onBlur but i've an error message "Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN"

Thanks for your help

I've tried to use OnBlur

Answer (score 0):

using onBlur

```
const checkEnteredValues = (inputValue) => {
   const value = inputValue.replace(/[A-Z]/g, "");
   setTask(value);
}
```